# Blackberry push notification implementation

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-push

How does one implement a push notification for a blackberry app?

I heard that in order to do so I need to purchase a Blackberry Enterprise Server which costs me 1400 per year. Is this true? Where is a good starting point in implementing push notifications?

I am experienced with iPhone push development, but cannot find the equivalent for blackberries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Earlier this year Blackberry launched a push service that does not require a BES, similar to Apple's offering.  The have a Java SDK for it.  You can find more information here: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/pushapi.jsp#tab_tab_overview

Comment: push notification works with wifi or gprs internet? whether i need BIS or Blackberry Enterprise Server?

Comment: you need BIS or BES to register for the push notification

Answer (score 2):

also check out UrbanAIrship, which offers blackberry push notifications as a service (BBPNaaS)

http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/

Answer (score 1):

Well, its true that you need a BES for Blackberry push services.

AFAIK,In a  "non BES environment", you can use a number of other methods such as email, SMS or polling to do the 'push'.

and the good news is: Check out foll. link :

http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1561689/rim-pushes-blackberry-software-development

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://cloudbase.io also is about to launch push notifications for BlackBerry on top of their cloud hosting services for mobile applications.