# HTTPpushdemo on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I'm blackberry beginner. I want to realize push notification from the server to my device.
I didn't know how to start.

1. I find an exemple Httppushdemo but I don't know how to try it ?
2. There is an sdk push notification should I installed this sdk
3. Should I installed tomcat and oracle to realize this push notification
4. There is also a file Pap that can used in push notification

What is the tool I can used. Can any one help me 
thanks

Comment: This has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733221/blackberry-push-notification-implementation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987301/blackberry-push-notification-tutorial

Comment: I see this link but there are others methods and I didn't understand what is the difference between this methods like "PAP" and I want to try the example in samples BlackBerry how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Push SDK is for developing server side code only. For client side (at ur device side) you can use Push API which is included in Blackberry JRE 5.0 and above. You can refer HttpPushDemo sample code from Blackberry API which uses MDS service or if you want to use BIS this code can be useful , http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857