# Push notification on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, client-server, push-notification

I need to send a notification to the BlackBerry device when new information is added to the server. The server should send the notification to the BlackBerry device and blackberry device should then receive this notification.

I installed the BlackBerry push SDK, and I obtain registration with the BlackBerry Push Service, but I didn't understand how to use it and when. What is the next step? What should I do for the client and server part?

Comment: refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733221/blackberry-push-notification-implementation

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry provide the sample demo "**HttpPushDemo**" in that you can get one "**readme**" file. Follow those rules. Enough. You can understand every thing.

Comment: I test this example but I didn't receive any notification in my simulator when I click send in the HTTP Push Demo Server window. Can you explain to me another thing ? if there is this sample example why we need registration  with the BlackBerry Push Service and the SDK push service. Where we need this informations?

Comment: When I click send in the HTTP Push Demo Server window, I obtain HTTP response code:400 for URL. I think because I didn't receive anything in my simulator.  So it didn't receive any response.

Comment: Before open the server run.bat file did you open the MDS server of specified version? Means First open the MDS server and run the client application. check the internet connection in simulator and then run the run.bat file on the server HttpPushDemo.

Comment: MDS is launched when I run my simulator. Then I check internet connection. After open client application that appear "HTTP Listen Object started". And when I click the run.bat in the server. The window of server appear. When I sent the message nothing happened in the application and I obtain the same error  HTTP response code:400 for URL. Should I modify something in the code or add something??

Comment: Go to http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Please-Help-for-my-application-client-amp-server/td-p/338204/page/5 and look at robmat's post. It solves the 400 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tongue in cheek - use Urban Airship! No i don't work for them, I just love their service, although I'm sure there are others out there so look for them too.

More seriously, if you are doing this for commercial reasons do bear it in mind as an option, but don't let it stop you expermenting! UA does involve writing your own server code too but gives some nice abstraction.