# Blackberry: Push Notification in Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me, push

Has anybody implemented push notifications for a BlackBerry application?

Comment: Have you check push demo apps in samples in BB jde folder?

Comment: u can download the code from http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/pushapi.jsp

Comment: Go this link and see the comment I gave: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353725/push-notification-on-blackberry/8355754#8355754

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

Blackberry provides an example application with the SDK and you can use the material on the blackberry website to see how to implement a push service:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/pushapi.jsp