# Blackberry Push Integration Client Sample Code

Tags: blackberry, push

I need a sample application code for push integration in my blackberry application. I have registered my application for the push credentials and have received them.

please help,

Kind Regards,
Rupesh

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481122/push-notification-in-blackberry and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396978/push-notification-with-blackberry-client-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fully working push application code it may be help you for implement push notification.

```
public class push_Main {

/**
 * Entry point for this application
 * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
 */

private static final String REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL = "rc=200";
private static final String DEREGISTER_SUCCESSFUL = REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL;
private static final String USER_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED = "rc=10003";
private static final String ALREADY_UNSUSCRIBED_BY_USER = "rc=10004";
private static final String ALREADY_UNSUSCRIBED_BY_PROVIDER = "rc=10005";

private static final String PUSH_PORT = "";  //push port
private static final String BPAS_URL = "http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
private static final String APP_ID = "";   // add application id
//  private static final String CONNECTION_SUFFIX = ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=seekrit string";

private static String URL = "http://:100"; // PORT 100 add your posh port.
private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 256;

public static ListeningThread _listeningThread;
public static StreamConnectionNotifier _notify;

private static final long ID = 0x954a603c0dee81e0L;


public push_Main() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    NotificationsManager.registerSource(ID, theSource, NotificationsConstants.IMPORTANT);
        if(_listeningThread==null)
        {
            System.out.println("msg on listening thread 1");        
            _listeningThread = new ListeningThread();
            System.out.println("msg on listening thread 2");
            _listeningThread.start();
            System.out.println("msg on listhning thread 3 ");


        } 


}
public static class ListeningThread extends Thread
{
    private boolean _stop = false;

    /**
     * Stops the thread from listening.
     */
    private synchronized void stop()
    {
        _stop = true;
        try 
        {
            // Close the connection so the thread will return.
            _notify.close(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {      

        }          
    }

    /**
     * Listen for data from the HTTP url. After the data has been read, 
     * render the data onto the screen.
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */

    public void run()
    {

        StreamConnection stream = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        MDSPushInputStream pushInputStream=null;

        while (!_stop)
        {
            try 
            {

                // Synchronize here so that we don't end up creating a connection that is never closed.
                synchronized(this)  
                {
                    // Open the connection once (or re-open after an IOException),  so we don't end up 
                    // in a race condition, where a push is lost if it comes in before the connection 
                    // is open again. We open the url with a parameter that indicates that we should 
                    // always use MDS when attempting to connect.
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg connection 1");
                    _notify = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(URL);
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg connection 2");

                }

                while (!_stop)
                {

                    // NOTE: the following will block until data is received.
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg notify 1");
                    stream = _notify.acceptAndOpen();
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg 1 ");

                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n\n msg 2");
                        input = stream.openInputStream();
                        System.out.println("\n\n msg 3 ");

                        pushInputStream= new MDSPushInputStream((HttpServerConnection)stream, input);

                        System.out.println("\n\n msg 4");
                        // Extract the data from the input stream.

                        DataBuffer db = new DataBuffer();

                        byte[] data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                        int chunk = 0;

                        while ( -1 != (chunk = input.read(data)) )
                        {
                            db.write(data, 0, chunk);
                        }

                        updateMessage(data);

                        // This method is called to accept the push.
                        pushInputStream.accept();                          

                        data = db.getArray();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e1) 
                    {
                        // A problem occurred with the input stream , however, the original 
                        // StreamConnectionNotifier is still valid.
                        //                          errorDialog(e1.toString());                   
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if ( input != null ) 
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                input.close();
                            } 
                            catch (IOException e2) 
                            {                  

                            }
                        }

                        if ( stream != null )
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                stream.close();
                            } 
                            catch (IOException e2) 
                            {                                    
                            }
                        }                                                 
                    }
                }                  
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                // Likely the stream was closed. Catches the exception thrown by 
                // _notify.acceptAndOpen() when this program exits.
                errorDialog(ioe.toString());        
            }
            finally
            {
                /*

                if ( _notify != null ) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        _notify.close();
                        _notify = null;
                    } 
                    catch ( IOException e ) 
                    {          

                    }
                }

                 */

            }
        }
    }
}


private static void updateMessage(final byte[] data)
{
    System.out.println("\n\n msg 6");

    Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            // Query the user to load the received message.

            //              Dialog.alert( new String(data));


            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(ID, 0, null, null);
                    Dialog d = new Dialog( Dialog.D_OK, new String(data) ,0, null, Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
                    //                      _dialogShowing = true;
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushGlobalScreen( d, 10, UiApplication.GLOBAL_MODAL );

                    // Dialog is closed at this point, so we cancel the event.                                        

                }
            } );


        }

    });
} 

public static void registerBpas() {

    /**
     * As the connection suffix is fixed I just use a Thread to call the connection code
     * 
     **/

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                final String registerUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, null) + Conn.getConnectionParameters();
                System.out.println("\n\n\n msg registerBPAS URL is:  "+ registerUrl);
                HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(registerUrl);
                InputStream is = httpConnection.openInputStream();
                String response = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is));
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg RESPOSE CODE :    " + response);
                close(httpConnection, is, null);
                String nextUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, response) + Conn.getConnectionParameters();
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg nextUrl :    " + nextUrl);
                HttpConnection nextHttpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(nextUrl);
                InputStream nextInputStream = nextHttpConnection.openInputStream();
                response = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(nextInputStream));
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg RESPOSE CODE 1:    " + response);
                close(nextHttpConnection, is, null);
                if (REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL.equals(response) || USER_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED.equals(response)) {
                    System.out.println("msg Registered successfully for BIS push");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("msg BPAS rejected registration");
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {

                System.out.println("msg IOException on register() " + e + " " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public static void close(Connection conn, InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    if (os != null) {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void errorDialog(final String message)
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Dialog.alert(message);
        } 
    });
}

private static String formRegisterRequest(String bpasUrl, String appId, String token) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bpasUrl);
    sb.append("/mss/PD_subReg?");
    sb.append("serviceid=").append(appId);
    sb.append("&osversion=").append(DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion());
    sb.append("&model=").append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    if (token != null && token.length() > 0) {
        sb.append("&").append(token);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Guys! By the way, can I implement **PushApplication** interface for receiving push in my application? I'm developing my application for 5.0 and 6.0 version phones.

Comment: Yes you receiving push massage in your application. it working on 5.0 and 6.0 also.

Comment: what is the value of theSource @NotificationsManager.registerSource(ID, theSource, NotificationsConstants.IMPORTANT);