# for receiving push notification on blackberry is BIS necessory?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing app for blackberry os 6 & 7 For receiving push notifications should I compulsory subscribe blackberry internet service plan from my service provider or any normal internet data plan or wi-fi networks  works for me. Please help. I am using blackberry curve 9220

Comment: its mandatory that you need BIS. Without BIS , you didnt get push notifications.

Comment: Yes, you need either BIS or BES.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry push notification implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733221/blackberry-push-notification-implementation)